# Stateful Axum middleware not compiling if wrapped in a Mutex

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum, rust-tower

I'm trying to implement a basic middleware in a Axum project, and I'm facing an issue when my middleware is passed a state wrapped in a Mutex.

##### Disclaimer

There is a high chance that the shared state used in this sample is not optimized nor recommended to use as-is in Axum. Above all I'm trying to understand the issue and learn how I could spot the underlying error in my code.

### The code

cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "mutex_sample"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
axum = "0.6.10"
tokio = {version = "1.26.0", features = ["full"]}
```

main.rs

```rust
use std::{
    net::SocketAddr,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

use axum::{
    extract::State,
    http::{Request, StatusCode},
    middleware::{self, Next},
    response::{IntoResponse, Response},
    routing::get,
    Router,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let state_with_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let state_without_mutex = Arc::new(0);

    let app: Router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(hello_world))
        // state without mutex compiles correctly
        .layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(state_without_mutex, test_middleware))
        // state with mutex : trait bound not satisfied
        .layer(middleware::from_fn_with_state(state_with_mutex, test_middleware_mutex));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));
    println!("Listening on {}", addr);

    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(app.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn hello_world() -> String {
    String::from("Hello Reachy !")
}

async fn test_middleware_mutex<B>(
    State(state): State<Arc<Mutex<u16>>>,
    request: Request<B>,
    next: Next<B>,
) -> Response {

    // Commenting this let-else expression fixes the compiler error
    let Ok(inner) = state.lock() else {
        return StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST.into_response();
    };

    next.run(request).await
}

async fn test_middleware<B>(
    State(state): State<Arc<u16>>,
    request: Request<B>,
    next: Next<B>,
) -> Response {

    if *state > 1 {
        return StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST.into_response();
    }

    next.run(request).await
}
```

##### The error

```
the trait bound `axum::middleware::FromFn<fn(State<Arc<std::sync::Mutex<u16>>>, Request<_>, Next<_>) -> impl Future<Output = Response<http_body::combinators::box_body::UnsyncBoxBody<axum::body::Bytes, axum::Error>>> {test_middleware_mutex::<_>}, Arc<std::sync::Mutex<{integer}>>, Route<_>, _>: tower_service::Service<Request<_>>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `tower_service::Service<Request>`:
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)>
  axum::middleware::FromFn<F, S, I, (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9)>
and 8 others
```

### Questions

Two behavior I don't understand here (despite the compiler error message) :

- as stated in the code, if I remove the `let-else` expression from `test_middleware_mutex()`, then everything compiles correctly. It seems that the multiple possible return type inside the function causes the compiler to complain.
- for the same type of code (`let-else` inside the async middleware), wrapping the state in a Mutex also causes an issue.

These two behaviors are mutually exclusive, I can fix the error by removing the `Mutex` or by removing the `let-else` expression, but I can't keep both.

Does someone know why is this code not working ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without looking too deep, I suspect it is complaining about a missing `Send` or `Sync` constraint since your mutex example holds the lock guard longer than you probably expect. Its held for the duration of the function including the `.await` and since the standard lock guard can't be shared between threads, the `Future` is not `Send` or `Sync`.

Comment: I think you are right. `MutexGuard`'s documentation states that 
`#[must_not_suspend = "holding a MutexGuard across suspend points can cause deadlocks, delays, and cause Futures to not implement Send"]`

I tried to add `drop(inner)` before the `.await` call in `test_middleware_mutex()`, the error remained. 

I then encapsulated the entire `let-else` expression with a block `{ }` causing the `MutexGuard` to drop by itself before the call to `.await` and it fixed the compiler error !

Why the manual drop did not work though ?

Comment: I believe the difference between `drop()` and `{ }` is a compiler bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/104883

Comment: Ok this makes sense then, thanks a lot for your indication ! 

After searching through some more documentation, I have found that tokio explains very well the issue here : https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use

std::Mutex should be used inside non-async methods to avoid any issues.

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

As stated in my post's comment section, this is a normal behavior for `std::sync::Mutex`.
It is well documented here : https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#which-kind-of-mutex-should-you-use

### TL;DR

`std::sync::Mutex` does not do well with `async` methods since they cannot be held across `Future`s. If `std::sync::Mutex` is used, manipulate it in non-async function. Otherwise, use some async-compatible mutex, such as Tokio's https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html#